# React-Native - reload data and rerender component when pop action is performed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 screens screen A and screen B, each page has different api calls to get data to be rendered in page.
from screen A to Screen B i pushed into stack by using
 `this.props.navigator.push({id: 'goToScreenB'});`
and user click on back button will go to screen B to Screen A by using `this.props.navigator.pop();`
when user go back from screen B to screen A i want to make api call to get the new data, at initial the api will be called at `componentWillMount` how to call `componentWillMount` of screen A when pop back from screen B.

Answer (score -2):

i cannot tell for sure without your code. But probably when you go back to screen A componentWillMount is going to be called.

You can place a console.log() and see if it is being called. If it is not being called you should use componentWillUpdate()

Comment: screenA componentWillMount is not called by using pop() from screenB ,componentWillReceiveProps() is called when i pop form screenB is there any way to identify i poped from this screen B so that i can do some special operation. My props have navigator object by default. is it possible to send one more key like {'navigator':{},'popfrom':'screen B'} with the props while executing `this.props.navigator.pop();`